# Automatically Update 2 Table or Multiple in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem

I want to ask, how to change the data that has been entered into the table rekap_nilai. which is where the table is rekapan rekap_nilai total of table nilai_student.

I enter a table B based on trigger

```
mysql> select * from nilai_student;
```

```
+----+-------+------+-------+
| id | name  | idmp | nilai |
+----+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | Udin  |    1 |    80 |
|  2 | Udin  |    2 |    60 |
|  3 | Mamat |    1 |    75 |
+----+-------+------+-------+
```

table rekap_nilai

```
mysql> desc rekap_nilai;
```

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| idstudent | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name      | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nilai     | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
mysql> select * from rekap_nilai;
```

```
+----+-----------+-------+-------+
| id | idstudent | name  | nilai |
+----+-----------+-------+-------+
|  1 |         1 | Udin  |   140 |
|  2 |         2 | Mamat |    75 |
+----+-----------+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What if there was a remedial student conduct and when **update** table nilai_student in column **nilai**, ​​automatically in table rekap_nilai in column nilai

example

now name 'Udin' have **nilai** 60 in **id** 2, and he want remedial. when he was remedial, I want to **update** he's nilai = 70 , and then in table rekap_nilai. udin automatically update to **nilai** = 150

Answer (score 1):

You can write a trigger which gets executed on update of table `nilai_student` , some thing like below

```
Delimiter ///
create trigger update_rekap_nilai after update on nilai_student 
for each row begin
update recap_nilai set nilai = nilai - Old.nilai + New.nilai where name=Old.name
end;
///
Delimiter ;
```

Hope this helps !!